# Ninject with Entity Framework - SqlException

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ninject

In my application I use stored procedures with Entity Framework. My problematic code below:

```
foreach (var order in Orders)
{
    _checkoutRepository.SaveOrderItem(...);

    foreach (var accessory in order.Accessories)
    {
        _checkoutRepository.SaveOrderItem(...);
    }

    foreach (var gift in order.Gifts)
    {
        _checkoutRepository.SaveOrderItem(...);
    }
}

if (topOrder.GiftVouchers.Any())
{
    _discountRepository.ReserveGiftVoucher(...);
}
```

As you can see, first, I save in a loop all order item. Everything works good here. But then I want to call any other procedure and I always get the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

My DbContext is binded like:

```
kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

Where is the problem? Why after foreach loops I always get this error? Is there any transaction limit? In my order procedures I do not use transactions, there are only inserts.

I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this exception because you're enumerating through a IEnumerable. A IEnumerable executes the queries while using the enumerator, so you can't modify the object. You need to get the full executed list and work with that. You have to convert your IEnumerable to an IList. Use the [ToList()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) function to convert it to an IList.